# Combobox_Change Function in MultiPages in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have multipage userform. I created a button, when I click to this button it adds a Combobox and some labels and textbox. Later I need to create a change funtion for this Combobox. But, I can't use the name of the Combobox.

```
Private Sub add_ndc_button_Click()
ndc_page_count = Me.ndc_pages.Pages.Count
Me.ndc_pages.Pages.Add ("NDC " & ndc_page_count + 1)

Set ndc_no_textbox_pages(ndc_page_count + 1) = ndc_pages.Pages(ndc_page_count).Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")
With ndc_no_textbox_pages(ndc_page_count + 1)
  .Top = first_c_y + space_between_rows
  .Left = first_c_x + space_between_columns
  .Height = text_height
  .Width = text_width
  .RowSource = "=ProductMasterData!F2:F19"
End With
End Sub
```

Then I need to create the following function using the name created with button click. But, ndc_no_textbox_pages(1)_Change() gives an error.

```
Public Sub ndc_no_textbox_pages(1)_Change()
Set SearchRangeNDC = Worksheets("ProductMasterData").Range("F1:F100")
Set FindRowNDC = SearchRangeNDC.Find(ndc_no_textbox.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
If FindRowNDC Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Please Enter Correct NDC Number or" & vbNewLine & "Select From Drop   Down Menu", vbOKOnly, "Required Field"
Else
NDCRow = FindRowNDC.Row
ndc_no_textbox_pages_label(1).Caption =      Worksheets("ProductMasterData").Range("F" & NDCRow) & vbNewLine & Worksheets("ProductMasterData").Range("N" & NDCRow)
End If
End Sub
```